# Firefox won't open on Ubuntu 22.04 (VM: UTM emulating on m2 MacBook Air)

Tags: firefox, xorg, 22.04, macbook

I'm rather new to the linux/ubuntu scene and I'm trying to get some experience with it. I've a MacBook Air m2 and I'm using UTM to emulate ubuntu 22.04 on it. I installed everything, I updated with
`sudo apt update`
and
`sudo ubuntu-driver update`  everyting possible but still firefox won't open. I found that if I log into ubuntu -xorg then Firefox would open (sometimes it crashes but eventually it opens). Problem is that with -xorg terminal won't open and I need both. more generally, with xorg my Ubuntu is very glitchy.

Is there a solution that doesn't require xorg? I believe that the issue is with the emulator, I wonder if there is a way of fixing it. Thanks in advance!

when launching it via terminal I get these messages and I've to kill the process

```
Gtk-Message: 10:01:24.676: Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.
[GFX1-]: glxtest: VA-API test failed: failed to initialise VAAPI connection.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
[2023-02-13T16:03:10Z ERROR viaduct::backend::ffi] Missing HTTP status
[2023-02-13T16:03:10Z ERROR viaduct::backend::ffi] Missing HTTP status
```

Comment: Disable GPU acceleration in FF settings.

Comment: thanks, I tried disabling hardware acceleration (is this what you mean?) from the setting in FF (after opening it in xorg) but still won't open in normal ubuntu

Comment: Start it in a terminal and see what happens there

Comment: Also try to disable 3D acceleration in VM settings if available.

Comment: updated the question, it seems I cannot disable the 3d acceleration on UTM since the options is greyed out ("GPU acceleration is supported")

Comment: You need to stop the machine before you change it.

Comment: yes, the vm was stopped, but still can't disable it

Comment: looks like 3d acceleration is not supported by UTM, hence is intentionally un-clickable

Comment: This is a problem with UTM, not with Ubuntu.